# Maintaining Git Fork of Hg Repository with Patches

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, hg-git

I am maintaining a git fork of an hg repository with some additional patches. What this means is that I have cloned the hg repository and then pushed that repository to a git repository following [these directions](http://hg-git.github.io/).

I then cloned the git repository, applied some commits and then pushed those commits to the git repository.

My history look like:

```
hg-head\      /git-head
    A-B-C-F'-G'
```

where `F'` and `G'` are my patches.

The hg developer now pushes some patches to the hg repos and I want to incorporate those changes into my fork. I would like to do so keeping the hg history intact. In other words, I want my final history in git to look like:

```
hg-head\        /git-head
    A-B-C-E-F'-G'
```

where `E` is the new commit on hg.

in git terminology this would be saying "I want to `rebase` my master branch onto origin/master".

My question is what commands do I execute in hg and/or git to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you didn't pull (your patches) from Git to local HG-repo, you can do nothing at HG-side
- If you pulled from Git, you'll get additional head ("anonymous branches") in local repository after pulling E from upstream repository. In order to linearize history (if you want it, while it isn't needed at "mediator"), you'll use the same (by name) command in Mercurial: `hg rebase`

*Just note*: You can simplify your workflow, if, instead of intermediate HG-node, you'll try to use [Mercurial bridge in Git](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/) (part of Git now) for direct accessing upstream Mercurial repo from your Git

Comment: `git config --global remote-hg.hg-git-compat true` and then `git remote add upstream "hg::https://..."`